# Left and right floated elements with clear removing spacing underneath

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, multiple-columns

So I have the following code:

```
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.evens-and-odds {
  div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 80px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      background-color: deeppink;
      &:before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content: "Odd: " counter(section);
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(even) {
      float: right;
      background-color: lime;
      &:before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content: "Even: " counter(section);
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3) {
     height: 200px 
    }
    &:nth-of-type(5) {
      height: 400px;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(6) {
      height: 300px;
    }
  }
}
```

Full demo below:

http://codepen.io/crashy/pen/QyBvyG

You will notice that under the larger elements there is white space on the opposite side (left or right). I essentially want the elements to flow up, the idea is that each column should be isolated but I can not use wrapping `div`'s to achieve this only floats (or some other CSS magic).

Would prefer an JavaScript free solution.

Comment: I think you should use bootstrap grid .http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

It's abit complicated if you want to do this in CSS. I recommend you by doing this in HTML, just split evens and odds in two divs and you will be good.

Alright. You can float all odds to the left, and remove the float from the evens. So the right side divs (evens) will be stacking up even if the left side divs (odds) is bigger and there will be no white-space.

This is my solution:

```
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.evens-and-odds {
  div {
    display: table;
    height: 80px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    &:nth-of-type(odd) {
      display: table-cell;
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      background-color: deeppink;
      &:before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content: "Odd: " counter(section);
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(even) {
      display: table-cell;
      float: right;
      clear: right;
      background-color: lime;
      &:before {
        counter-increment: section;
        content: "Even: " counter(section);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

English is not my first language, sorry if im just rambling or something.

Comment: Hey that works really well, but only if the elements on the left side are longer, I have updated pen (http://codepen.io/crashy/pen/QyBvyG) so now if click on elements they expand, try expanding the right side and you will see the white space.

Comment: Alright, found another solution and I think it will work perfectly.

I edited my previous answer.

Comment: Still getting the same issue. I'm starting to think this may not work css only.